# Symbolic Link to folder not working as expected

Tags: linux, symlink

so i want to start tomcat server, to do this i have to run a script whose path is the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.6/libexec/bin/strartup.sh
```

Since it is tedious to remember this, i made a simbolic link:

```
tomcatsh/startup.sh
```

so with the ln command tomcatsh points to /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.6/libexec/bin

There is a problem when i run the shortened version, it yelds an error saying that the startup.sh script couldn't find setclasspath.sh . 
this other script is in the same folder, and it is not missing, why doesn't startup find that script? What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Without seeing how `startup.sh` looks for `setclasspath.sh`, it's hard to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you just create an alias?

Comment: @Barmar what is that?

Comment: It's a shell shortcut. You type the alias, and it's as if you typed the full command. `alias starttc=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.6/libexec/bin/startup.sh`

Comment: Put that in your `.bashrc` Then you can type `starttc` to run the startup script.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If previously that symlink is defined for the folder of the file, you have to call command with update parameter

```
ln -sf <file> <symlink>
```

rather than creation parameter

```
ln -s <file> <symlink>
```